# Attempting to rewrite a very lengthy query

Tags: plsql, common-table-expression

I am currently trying to improve on a query that is being used to build a view.  The query is in PL/SQL, in an Oracle database.  There are 3 different types of reports (100,200, and 300) that are generated at each building.  We track the consecutive years that each report is generated, and based on the combination of (1) the type(s) of report(s) generated for a given year and (2) the consecutive years each report has been generated, we arrive at a Result type for that building.

Here is a description of the criteria for the Result types:

Result 600 - If all 3 report types have been generated in the current year, where:
 Level 1: all reports were generated in 1 consecutive year (this is the first year)
 Level 2: at least 1 report type has been generated for 2 consecutive years (none have 3  consecutive years)
 Level 3: at least one report type has been generated for 3 consecutive years

Result 100 - Only report type 100 has been generated in the current year, where:
 Level 1 - 1 consecutive year
 Level 2 - 2 consecutive years
 Level 3 - 3 consecutive years

Result 200 - Only report type 200 has been generated in the current year, where:
 Level 1 - 1 consecutive year
 Level 2 - 2 consecutive years
 Level 3 - 3 consecutive years

Result 300 - Only report type 300 has been generated in the current year, where:
 Level 1 - 1 consecutive year
 Level 2 - 2 consecutive years
 Level 3 - 3 consecutive years

Result 400 - Only reports 100 and 200 have been generated, where:
 Level 1: both reports were generated in 1 consecutive year (this is the first year)
 Level 2: at least 1 report type has been generated for 2 consecutive years (neither have 3  consecutive years)
 Level 3: at least one report type has been generated for 3 consecutive years

Result 500 - Only reports 100 and 300 have been generated, where:
 Level 1: both reports were generated in 1 consecutive year (this is the first year)
 Level 2: at least 1 report type has been generated for 2 consecutive years (neither have 3  consecutive years)
 Level 3: at least one report type has been generated for 3 consecutive years

Result 700 - Only reports 200 and 300 have been generated, where:
 Level 1: both reports were generated in 1 consecutive year (this is the first year)
 Level 2: at least 1 report type has been generated for 2 consecutive years (neither have 3  consecutive years)
 Level 3: at least one report type has been generated for 3 consecutive years

Still with me?  Sweet.  So here is the current code that is used to generate this view, which is simply a display of the result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW REPORTS.REPORT_RESULT_VIEW
(
   BUILDING,
   BUILDING_NAME,
   GROUP,
   YEAR,
   TYPE,
   SUBTYPE,
   CONSEC,
   RESULT
)
AS
   WITH cte1
        AS (SELECT 1 ID_100,
                   1 ID_200,
                   1 ID_300,
                   '600 Level 1' RESULT
              FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID_100,
                   2 ID_200,
                   2 ID_300,
                   '600 Level 2' RESULT
              FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 ID_100,
                   3 ID_200,
                   3 ID_300,
                   '600 Level 3' RESULT
              FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 ID_100,
                   1 ID_200,
                   2 ID_300,
                   '600 Level 2' RESULT
              FROM DUAL),
```

(note - there are 63 total combinations that are listed in the actual code... I only entered the first few to give you an idea of how it is set up)

```
        cte2
        AS (  SELECT MAX (ID_100) ID_100_CONSEC,
                     MAX (ID_200) ID_200_CONSEC,
                     MAX (ID_300) ID_300_CONSEC,
                     YEAR,
                     BUILDING
                FROM (SELECT CONSEC ID_100,
                             NULL ID_200,
                             NULL ID_300,
                             YEAR,
                             TYPE || SUBTYPE TYPE,
                             BUILDING
                        FROM REPORT_MASTER_VIEW
                       WHERE TYPE || SUBTYPE = '100'
                      UNION
                      SELECT NULL ID_100,
                             CONSEC ID_200,
                             NULL ID_300,
                             YEAR,
                             TYPE || SUBTYPE TYPE,
                             BUILDING
                        FROM REPORT_MASTER_VIEW
                       WHERE TYPE || SUBTYPE = '200'
                      UNION
                      SELECT NULL ID_100,
                             NULL ID_200,
                             CONSEC ID_300,
                             YEAR,
                             TYPE || SUBTYPE TYPE,
                             BUILDING
                        FROM REPORT_MASTER_VIEW
                       WHERE TYPE || SUBTYPE = '300')
            GROUP BY YEAR, BUILDING),
        cte3
        AS (SELECT c2.*, c1.RESULT
              FROM    cte2 c2
                   JOIN
                      cte1 c1
                   ON     NVL (c2.ID_100_CONSEC, 0) = c1.ID_100
                      AND NVL (c2.ID_200_CONSEC, 0) = c1.ID_200
                      AND NVL (c2.ID_300_CONSEC, 0) = c1.ID_300)
     SELECT t1."BUILDING",
            t1."BUILDING_NAME",
            t1."GROUP",
            t1."YEAR",
            t1."TYPE",
            t1."SUBTYPE",
            t1."CONSEC",
            t2.RESULT
       FROM    REPORT_MASTER_VIEW t1
            JOIN
               cte3 t2
            ON t1.BUILDING  = t2.BUILDING AND t1.YEAR = t2.YEAR
      WHERE T1.TYPE IN ('100', '200' '300')
   ORDER BY t1.BUILDING;
```

Now, because for every report combination, it has to run through all the possible combinations, this view takes about 24 seconds to build.  In the app that it is referenced in, it takes nearly a minute to load the page.  For this reason, I am trying to figure out ways to make the query more efficient.  At first, I was thinking of using nested CASE statements, but I wasn't really sure how that would work.  Any suggestions on how to better approach this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try codereview.stackexchange.com. We're here to answer programming questions, not to optimize/review your code.

Comment: @MarcB wtf? there are 127,783 results for "slow" on stackoverflow and most of the top results pertain to slow code problems. consider this question which got 4,886 upvotes and whose answer got 7,507 upvotes. stop bullying new users. slow sql queries are notorious problems and very different from "code review". user2493382 your question is very welcome on stackoverflow. just take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte2 AS
(
        SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE || SUBTYPE = '100' THEN CONSEC END) AS ID_100_CONSEC
        ,       MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE || SUBTYPE = '200' THEN CONSEC END) AS ID_200_CONSEC
        ,       MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE || SUBTYPE = '300' THEN CONSEC END) AS ID_300_CONSEC
        ,       YEAR
        ,       BUILDING
        FROM    REPORT_MASTER_VIEW
        WHERE   TYPE || SUBTYPE IN ('100', '200', '300')
        GROUP   BY
                YEAR
        ,       BUILDING
)
,cte3 AS
(
        SELECT  ID_100_CONSEC
        ,       ID_200_CONSEC
        ,       ID_300_CONSEC
        ,       YEAR
        ,       BUILDING
        ,       CASE
                    WHEN c2.ID_100_CONSEC = 1 THEN '600 Level 1' 
                    WHEN c2.ID_100_CONSEC = 2 THEN '600 Level 2' 
                    WHEN c2.ID_100_CONSEC = 3 THEN '600 Level 3' 
                    WHEN c2.ID_200_CONSEC = 1 THEN '600 Level 1' 
                    WHEN c2.ID_200_CONSEC = 2 THEN '600 Level 2' 
                    WHEN c2.ID_200_CONSEC = 3 THEN '600 Level 3' 
                    WHEN c2.ID_300_CONSEC = 1 THEN '600 Level 1' 
                    WHEN c2.ID_300_CONSEC = 2 THEN '600 Level 2' 
                    WHEN c2.ID_300_CONSEC = 3 THEN '600 Level 3' 
                END AS RESULT
        FROM    cte2
        WHERE   c2.ID_100_CONSEC IN (1, 2, 3)
        OR      c2.ID_200_CONSEC IN (1, 2, 3)
        OR      c2.ID_300_CONSEC IN (1, 2, 3)
)
SELECT  t1."BUILDING",
        t1."BUILDING_NAME",
        t1."GROUP",
        t1."YEAR",
        t1."TYPE",
        t1."SUBTYPE",
        t1."CONSEC",
        t2.RESULT
FROM    REPORT_MASTER_VIEW t1
WHERE   T1.TYPE IN ('100', '200', '300')
AND     EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    cte3 t2
            WHERE   t1.BUILDING  = t2.BUILDING
            AND     t1.YEAR = t2.YEAR
        )
ORDER   BY
        t1.BUILDING;
```

Should be pretty close. I think you will need to polish it a little.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps.